# SSH key stop working on MAC OS Sierra 10.12.3 in source tree

Tags: git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

Source tree was working fine using SSH but after upgrading my mac to 'OS Sierra' it stop working.
Giving Error Permission Denied.

Please Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal and type "ssh-add", when prompted type in the password for your SSH RSA key.
To verify if you have an SSH RSA key in your profile, type "ssh-add -L". After upgrading to Sierra it will say something like "The agent has no identities".

Comment: Thanks for ur answer let me check

Answer (score 1):

macOS Sierra changed the agent behavior for ssh. You can restore the old behavior, though. Add this to the top of `~/.ssh/config`:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

If you would like to store key passphrases in the keychain, you can also add:

```
UseKeychain yes
```